# Is it likely that American Mathematical Monthly would eventually accept a Filler article if it asks for substantial re-writing?

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals

The email with the initial review says the Filler has "some promise" , but says the writing is poor , and asks for detailed revisions for "further consideration". I'm not particularly keen on spending a lot of time re-writing and correcting the pedantic details, if there is a substantial chance of rejection after that revision.

Comment: How is this off-topic? It is prefectly possible to answer, as Pete did, and it seems generalisable enough. Mathematics is not my field, but I would guess that there are more people trying to publish in this paper than just the op.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mathematical journals go, the *Monthly* is actually quite selective: I believe their acceptance rate is something like 10%.  For the majority of the papers submitted, the answer is a hard "no."  For instance, I have submitted five papers to the *Monthly* and three of them were accepted.  For the other two, the rejection was very clear -- they sure did not say "some promise" or "further consideration," so when they say that I think they mean it.

The other thing to know about the *Monthly* is that they are extremely picky about exposition.  They care so much more about that than any other math journal I know.  Just a few hours ago I received a rejection from a prestigious journal, which described my paper as "very nicely written." The point being that they noticed but didn't really care: they want to publish papers with amazing breakthroughs.  The *Monthly* is not like that: they take the style about as seriously as the content.  And though indeed I think of myself as as strong, experienced writer, all three of my accepted *Monthly* articles required massive, repeated expository revisions.  They are really tireless: if after five times you haven't gotten it right, they will ask for a sixth revision.  (This is *not* an exaggeration.)

A "Filler" is of course much shorter than an article: obviously it can be no longer than a page.  The amount of expository work per line is probably going to be higher than just about any other math piece you could write.  You say

> I'm not particularly keen on spending a lot of time re-writing and correcting the pedantic details, if there is a substantial chance of rejection after that revision.

As I said above, I don't think they're stringing you along.  Based on the response you've gotten, I think you should expect that if you pay *enough* attention to the exposition, they'll probably take it in the end.  Do be aware though that we're talking about lots of work, for something that is not even going to be counted as an academic publication by most.  So if you really do not enjoy the writing process, you may end up feeling that the outlay of time and effort was not worth the reward.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. One of the comments that a reviewer made, suggests that he thinks that my proof does not deal with all possible cases of the problem, when in fact it actually does, and the confusion was likely borne out of my inadequate writing. I'm amused that they still thought it worthy, given they might have thought the proof was incomplete.

Comment: It turns out the initial review was just some review by their editorial board. They sent the revised version to two new referees, and both of them said this doesn't merit publication in AMM, and and they promptly rejected it.

Comment: @Aritro: I'm sorry to hear that.  Did the reviews explain to your satisfaction why the filler was not accepted?

Comment: Yes, one of them went into a lot of detail. The other one just said the manuscript was correct but not worthy enough.